# move my local site to host

Tags: php, mysql

I have write a local website via php, and now I put it on host and domain and i have some problem to connect to the mysql and I got folowing eror:

```
Connection failed: Access denied for user ''@'176.31.33.116' (using password: NO)
```

my code are according to below:
part of my index.php:

```
                        <?php
                        $DB_HOST = 'ghadir1.shatelhost.com';
                        $DB_USER = '';
                        $DB_PASS = '';
                        $DB_NAME = 'minewebs_sahar';
                        $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
                        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
                    } else {
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users AS u JOIN scores AS s ON (s.user_id=u.id) ORDER BY score DESC";
                        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
                        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            ?>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><?php echo "نام:" . $row['name'] . " امتیاز:" . $row['score']; ?></li>
                            <?php
```

what should i do tu solve my data base connection?

Comment: You are trying to connect without providing any mysql credentials. Your hosting provider certainly gave you some _if_ you are granted access to use their MySQL server. _Use them_.

Comment: Set correct username and password.

Answer (score 0):

You try to connect to a db host without credentials?
If No:
I would say, that your external db host doesn't allow external access.

Did you connect from your local system to ghadir1.shatelhost.com?

If yes:
I think you have to specify the user credentials

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error string,  I can say there is some issue with provided username and password. Mysql is not allowing you too connect to database with given credentials. Please check whether database credentials are right.

$DB_USER = '';
$DB_PASS = '';
You cannot login to database without username. You've to provide username and password to connect the mysql database.